# Where am I getting wrong in the destructor for this C++ container?

Tags: c++, memory-management, memory-leaks, stl, destructor

I am dealing with a `map`, whose second element is also a `map`, whose second element is a `vector`. And during the map building process it seems I have to allocate the memory dynamically, but then I fail to release the memory properly. My problem can be reduced to the source code below.

I just cannot figure out why the **desctructor** is incorrect.

Also, is there any better way to avoid memory leak in this case?

```
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

typedef vector<int> IntVect;
typedef map<int, IntVect> NumEle;
typedef map<int, NumEle> Nums;

class NumLess {
 public:
  Nums numSet;
  ~NumLess() {
    for (Nums::iterator I = numSet.begin(), E = numSet.end(); I != E; ++I) {
      NumEle &numEle = I->second;
      for (NumEle::iterator II = numEle.begin(), EE = numEle.end(); II != EE; ++II) {
        IntVect &intVect = II->second;
        intVect.clear();
        delete &intVect;
      }
      delete &numEle;
    }
  }
  friend ostream &operator<<(ostream &os, const NumLess &numLess) {
    for (Nums::const_iterator I = numLess.numSet.begin(),
                              E = numLess.numSet.end();
         I != E; ++I) {
      const NumEle &numEle = I->second;
      os << "NumEle:" << I->first << endl;
      for (NumEle::const_iterator II = numEle.begin(), EE = numEle.end();
           II != EE; ++II) {
        os << "IntVect  " << II->first << " | ";
        const IntVect &intVect = II->second;
        for (auto i : intVect) {
          os << i << " ";
        }
        os << endl;
      }
    }
    return os;
  }
};

int main(void) {
  NumLess numLess;
  for (unsigned h = 4; h > 0; --h) {
    NumEle *numEle = new NumEle();
    for (unsigned i = h; i > 0; --i) {
      IntVect *intVect = new IntVect();
      for (unsigned j = 0; j < i; ++j) {
        intVect->push_back(j);
      }
      numEle->insert(pair<int, IntVect>(i, *intVect));
    }
    numLess.numSet.insert(pair<int, NumEle>(h, *numEle));
  }
  cout << numLess;
  cout << "finished" << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: [Don't use `new`](http://klmr.me/slides/modern-cpp/#1) and you've already greatly lowered your chances of a memory leak.

Comment: @chris But I just don't know the right data structure to avoid use of `new`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make a long story very short : you are deleting object that you didn't allocate. To fix it, you need to remove deletes from your destructor.

You also have a leak in your main. You are creating objects on heap, and never releasing. The created objects are copied into the containers. To fix this leak, remove new, and just add objects into containers.

---

If you prefer to work with pointers (bad in my opinion), you need to change your typedefs :

```
typedef map<int, IntVect*> NumEle;
typedef map<int, NumEle*> Nums;
```

---

Here is 'main()' without 'new' and memory leak :

```
int main(void) {
  NumLess numLess;
  for (unsigned h = 4; h > 0; --h) {
    NumEle numEle;
    for (unsigned i = h; i > 0; --i) {
      IntVect intVect;
      for (unsigned j = 0; j < i; ++j) {
        intVect.push_back(j);
      }
      numEle.insert(pair<int, IntVect>(i, intVect));
    }
    numLess.numSet.insert(pair<int, NumEle>(h, numEle));
  }
  cout << numLess;
  cout << "finished" << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: But I think I am using the destructor to release the memory indirectly.

Comment: @HongxuChen Just remove rows with 'new' and 'delete' in your code, and see how that fixes your program. Your destructor doesn't have to do anything. Contrainer's destructor will do what needs to be done.

Comment: I just find that it is hard for me to make the code runnable without `new`. For instance, `numEle` will be destroyed once the loop is finished(`Am I right?`), and in the real code, I have to use `numLess.numSet` for future use.

Comment: But can we guarantee that after this initialization, the allocated will not be released so that `numLess` data info can be used in other functions if it is passed to the function? Is it possible that the allocated space is released unexpectedly?

Comment: @HongxuChen What do you mean released unexpectedly? Of course, it will work fine

Comment: I mean that after the insertion operation, there is another function call which passes `numLess`; and in that function, can we guarantee that the `numLess.numSet` still holds those memories rather than released. I am just not sure about the time when STL container memory(in thise case, the space of each mapped value) is destroyed.

Comment: @HongxuChen What is passed to 'insert' method is copied. Therefore, all is released nicely.

Comment: Thanks, I later followed your advice and realized that. And so the memory is allocated on the stack instead of heap, thus there is a memory leak in main and deleting in the destructor is incorrect?

Comment: @HongxuChen More or less. The containers are using heap for it's elements, but it takes care of the memory. So, do not worry